# Trouble getting subsequent Xpath queries to work

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I'm trying to access the multiple items across multiple Xpath queries, while using the first query as a base.

I tried:

```
$playerinfo = $xpath->query('//*[@class="PlayerHeader"]');
$playername = $xpath->query('/h3/a', $playerinfo);
echo $playername->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Nothing is returned. If I do

```
$playerinfo = $xpath->query('//*[@class="PlayerHeader"]/h3/a');
echo $playerinfo->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

It works fine. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$playerinfo is a list of matching nodes - when you use it as the context for a subsequent search, the context can only be a SINGLE node, not a node list:

```
$playername = $xpath->query('/h3/a', $playerinfo->item(0));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$playername = $xpath->query('/h3/a', $playerinfo);
```

You are trying to evaluate an *absolute* XPath expression against a node -- that isn't meaningful.

An absolute expression is always evaluated having the document node as context node.

there is no `/h3` node (the top element is probably `html`, not `h3`, and due to this, there is no `/h3/a` node also).

**Solution**: Use a *relative* expression: `h3/a`.

**Recommendation**: Read about "Relative and Absolute XPath expressions" and understand this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, helped me a lot. Just for anyone else viewing this, the correct code is


$playername = $xpath->query('./h3/a', $playerinfo->item(0));

since I'm not using this in a foreach and only wanted to access a single node.